# How do you put a letter triangle in a file?

Tags: c++

So this is for some homework I am working on.

I've been working on this for days now. I need to print a letter triangle,

example

```
a
aa
aaa
```

to a file I create in the code. I have gotten the triangle part down using a for loop but cannot figure out how to get it into a file. here is what I have so far.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream> 
using namespace std;

char loop()
{ for (int i = 1; i <=15; i++){
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++){
        cout << "a";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
}

int main()
{
    ofstream week2 ("week2assignment.txt");
    
    if (week2.is_open()){
        char result = loop();

        {
            week2 << loop() + "\n";
        }
    }
    week2.close();
    else cout << "file wasnt created";
    return 0;
}
```

This is my first post on here and I am in my second week of learning C++ so any help would be appreciated immensely. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: I have one in my code I must have forgot to add it here. I edited the post to reflect that.

Comment: You could use `fstream` to open a file and add to it.

Comment: Before asking us questions, you could've looked this up on google, printing to file is easily available on the internet, if not, use this link : https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Comment: didn't I do that with the ofstream week2 ("week2assignment.txt")?

Comment: Using `std::cout` only works with printing to the console, for printing to the file, use `week2 << "text";`

Comment: Please indent your code properly. Otherwise it is harder to read the intentions of your code and find any deficiencies.

Comment: Your `loop()` doesn't return anything, so at line `week2 << loop() + "\n` wouldn't add anything to yout file. This is another issue.

Comment: Your `loop()` prints to the console, which is not bliss at all, if you want to print to the file.

Answer (score 5):

You just need to replace `cout` with `week2` everywhere, since `cout` is the terminal and `week2` is your file.

Given the current structure of your code, where you write to `cout` in a function, you'll need to pass `week2` as an argument to that function to use it there.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, [don't build a habit of using using namespace std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

`std::endl` will put a linebreak, but it will also flush your stream. Put easily, outputting something is a really costly (=takes a long time) action in regard to other actions. To account for this, streams are buffered and once the buffer is full it will be flushed automatically. When you use `std::endl` the buffer might be flushed prematurely and this will tank performance. This is of course not really an issue in this small exercise, but I think it's still good to know. You can use `\n` instead. Although it might not look like it, it will provide a platform independend linebreak and should virtually always be used instead of `std::endl`.

Then consider what your function `loop` should do. Right now, you said it has return type `char` but it's not returning something. Therefore you should correct this and specify that this function is not returning anything, but just performing an action, hence return type `void`.

As suggested by John Zwinck, if you pass the stream as an argument, your function becomes more powerful and works with any kind of outgoing stream (i.e. `std::ostream`).

We can  make the function even more generic, but I'll leave it to you to understand the code (if not, feel free to post a comment for clarification). Please note also, that `loop` is not a descriptive name. I have no idea what `loop` does. Always give your functions a name that makes it clear what they are doing.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream> 

void print_letter_triangle(std::ostream& out, char c = 'a', int count = 15)
{ 
    for( int i = 0; i < count; i++ ){
        for( int j = 0; j < i; j++ )
        {
            out << c;
        }
         out << '\n';
    }
}

int main()
{
    // for testing purposes
    print_letter_triangle(std::cout);
    print_letter_triangle(std::cout, 'b');
    print_letter_triangle(std::cout, 'c', 7);
    
    std::ofstream week2("week2assignment.txt");
    
    if( week2.is_open() )
    {
        print_letter_triangle(week2);
        week2.close();
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Error: File wasn't created.\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Lastly: Try to build an early habit of how you want to format your code, positions of curly braces, spaces around operators. Right now it was a little bit inconsistent (which might as well have been caused by putting it on StackOverflow).

There are a couple more nitpicks one can offer (for example, I changed the loop to start from `0` and used the `<` instead of the `<=` operator, you can convince yourself that this does not change the number of loop iterations. However, it is common in programming languages to start from `0` (as counter-intuitive as that might be at first). Finally, since negative counting values do not make sense in this loop, one might change `int` to `unsigned int`, but I felt that might have been a little too much. Feel free to do so on your own, if you wish).

Comment: Good information. You can also restructure your code in main with a single `if (!week2.is_open()) {std::cerr << "Error: File wasn't created.\n"; return 1;}` and save the level of indention for your desired code-path. While it matters little with a single `if`, as code grows in complexity, it makes things much more readable. Also worth noting, `return 0;` is the default exit code for `main()` and can be omitted. (though it doesn't hurt anything to leave it just the way it is)

Answer (score -3):

I suggest you use this code:

```html
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream> 
using namespace std;

const char* loop()
{ for (int i = 1; i <=15; i++){
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++){
        return "a";
        }
        return "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    ofstream week2 ("week2assignment.txt");
    week2 << loop() << "\n";
    return 0;   
}
```

You must return a value from your `loop()` function.

Comment: I suggest you test your code before putting it in an answer. Code with compile errors generally isn't helpful: https://godbolt.org/z/TGvTjrrb6

Comment: I apologise for my ignorance, I'll correct my code

Comment: So that only returns "a" in the file. The loop works by itself I just can't figure out how to get that output to the file.